# javax.ws.rs: What is Actually Returned by a Method

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jetty

Am working on a REST API. This sample here works fine but am really confused about something here. My method getAll returns a String but the method has been annotated to Produce MIME MediaType of JSON. My question is , is the final returned response (doc)  a JSONObject or just a json String(Thus a String in JSON format). So that I can know how to handle the response when I get it.

```
    @Path("/membership/{pageNumber}")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getAll(@PathParam("pageNumber") String pageNumber){

        Map<String , String > params = new HashMap<>();
        String doc = HTTPClient.sendGet("localhost:9500/users/list/membership/field/"
                      +pageNumber, params, 60);

        return doc;
    }
```

This will really help me in my documentation as well.
All efforts are appreciated,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is , is the final returned response (doc) a JSONObject or
>   just a json String(Thus a String in JSON format)

Yes it will return the **json String**,If you want to send JSON and HTTP Status together you can use [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) as your return type.

Example:

```
@GET
@Path("/testGet")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response testGet() {
    String json = //Create JSON String
    return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

Comment: Please the Response, what library does it belongs to, because its not working for the libraries am importing

Comment: It's [Jax-Rs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0)

Comment: ohh sorry for that my return type was still String...I have changed it now and it works.

Comment: Thanks alot, it really helped

Answer (score 1):

> What is Actually Returned by a Method

Exactly what you return. This is Java. That is how Java works. There is not magic voodoo.

---

Maybe you're wondering something else.

All responses are written to the response output stream. It doesn't matter what the return type is. What matters is that there is a `MessageBodyWriter` that knows how to write that type to the output stream based on the `@Produces` content type. If the return type is a String, then there needs to be a writer that knows how to handle `String-application/json` combination. If the return type is `JSONObject`, then there need to be a writer that can handle *that*.

**See Also:** [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)

The client needs to know nothing about any Java types (i.e. Sting, JSONObect, etc). It gets the data a stream of bytes and converts the data with whatever conversion method it uses.

Answer (score 1):

You finally produce a JSON string.

Instead of just returning String it is recommended to use Entity

```
return Response.ok().entity(doc).build();
```

Comment: the returned statement you specified also returns a JSON String?

Comment: Thanks alot, really appreciate